# Adding while loop to try and except statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, mutagen

```
# import mutagen

from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

from mutagen.mp4 import MP4

from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

# Define a function to read ID3 tags

def readid3mp3 (ip):

    audio = MP3(ip)

    print(audio['TALB'])
    print(audio['TIT2'])
    print(audio['TPE1'])
    return
```

Im having a problem adding a while loop onto this part of the code. As you can see if the user does not enter a music file its prints ("ooooops this is not a music file") but if this happens i want the program to keep asking until the user enters a music file.

```
####### main body ########

# prompt user to enter a MP4

song = input('enter a music file please:') 

try:

     readid3mp4(song)

except IOError:

    print("ooooops this is not a music file")

else:

    print("music file stored")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a while loop, where you break after reading correctly the song. Otherwise, if an exception is thrown, the error message is printed and you continue normally.

```
while True:
    try:
        readid3mp4(song)
    except IOError:
        print("ooooops this is not a music file")
    else:
        break
```